# Splitting of electronic states in Tanabe-Sugano-diagrams

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

In Tanabe-Sugano-diagrams, different electronic transitions of term symbols of a given symmetry are shown. However, these electronic states arise due to splitting of term symbols of spherical to octahedral symmetry. What does this mean? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanabe%E2%80%93Sugano_diagram)

Does "spherical" mean the usual term symbol splitting in gaseous metal ions, where all the d-orbitals are degenerate because they have no ligands? And octahedral symmetry the different electronic states that arise due to the d-orbital splitting?

[image]

For example, in a gaseous metal ion the state $^{9}G$ would split into the four given states in an octahedral ligand field?

Comment: Yes. The (potential) splitting is purely a reflection of the symmetry.

Comment: Okay that makes sense